# Using eslint and prettier with Nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js

I've added eslint and prettier with instruction from https://nuxtjs.org/guide/development-tools/#eslint-and-prettier on my new nuxt project.

As soon as I `npm run lintfix` I get errors, eg.  `16:1   error  Insert`········                                 `prettier/prettier`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct command is

```
npm run lint --fix
```